# How to transform a dataframe so that the categories in a column become separate columns while the rows become individual elements without duplicates?

Tags: r, text, data-wrangling

How can I transform this dataframe so that each emotion_type (anger, sadness etc) becomes a separate column displaying their emotional frequency for each date, and each date is a row (i.e 2016-06-24 is row 1, 2016-07-01 is row 2 etc) [group_by and summarised df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59V8S.png)
The original data source looks like this: [original df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykpl5.png)

Tried using tidyverse functions e.g. group_by and spread as shown below, but yielded that output instead

```
library(dplyr)

filteredemotion2 <- filteredemotion1 %>% 
  arrange(timestamp) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(emotion_count > 0) %>% 
  group_by(date, emotion_type) %>% 
  summarise(Emotion_Count = sum(emotion_count))
```

Comment: Please share a small sample of input as copy/pasteable text, not as a screenshot. `dput()` is the easiest way to produce sample data, e.g., `dput(filteredemotion1[1:10, c("timestamp", "emotion_count", date", "emotion_type")])` for the first 10 rows of those columns.

Comment: I believe you can simply  add `pivot_wider(id=date, names_from=emotion_type, values_from=Emotion_Frequency)` to your summarized data (`pivot_wider()` is from `tidyr` package)